# Create a lookup type using one of the fields in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to create a lookup-data-type that store constant information. Usually I do something as follows:

```
const ROLES: { [key in "admin" | "viewer" | "creator"]: Role } = {
    admin: {id: "admin", name: "Administrator"},
    viewer: {id: "viewer", name: "Viewer"},
    creator: {id: "creator", name: "Creator"}
};
```

Is there a way to avoid having to repeat role (e.g. "admin") multiple times?

I want to be able to access role object with `ROLES.admin`, and I want that object to include both `id` and `name`.

These roles are "well-known" values.

Comment: Are the values of `id` and `name` just strings as in every string or is it required e.g. for the object ROLES.admin to have the same role name as ID?

Comment: @ddprrt, not sure I understand your question; but key in `ROLES` should match `id` in the contained `Role` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function that takes an object without ids, then inserts them in:

```
function insertIds<K extends string>(obj: Record<K, Omit<Role, "id">>): Record<K, Role> {
    const ret = {} as Record<K, Role>;
    for (const key in obj) {
        ret[key] = {id: key, ...obj[key]};
    }
    return ret;
}

const ROLES = insertIds({
    admin: {name: "Administrator"},
    viewer: {name: "Viewer"},
    creator: {name: "Creator"}
});
```

[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsA2KDeAoZQ5YAEwC5kBnMKUAcwG4CiQ4BbCC62kRvAXzx4YAVxAIwwdCGIhK0MAEkSlADwBpZBAAekECqo16APgAU6AEYArCqggJ0UEhoA0yAPJtgYVRmxuAIlIA42MASlt7R2d1Nz8IY2R8ImQHOTBkKAgMgF4k-mQ4SjQop1c0LASmFJhHZFM06mQAawgAT1lkSyswpOYUwiywAG1WtoBdZDycUgoxtwA6Je7R9vH+aqJBFKGRKBkhpkE8RozUdwAZAFEAZSnZeSglFVNkojgSLxAKHFYOCgCAEFPqBgNw4GBHAF+C5+sgAG7ACAAd2gPz+nGQAQAakjUVBobCUggshDHOj2JiAgBhUmQgmCfhhJgnaSUSoLTDoOimc7XG7MvAAegAVHg3gEPl8Aj84UESDKsVLQAEiUQAhjFUCQSAwTQyQTmDDmAFESjoIq3oR5VqzfjVXLNQDcebDYRjdaSRADZa5cEAV6fWrrU6sbTvfSAkaBMg8CKhUA)

Comment: I still have to repeat "admin" twice (which is what I'm trying to avoid).

Comment: @THX-1138 I've edited my answer. You can remove the type annotation and it'll infer correctly.

Comment: I don't understand how `K` got reduced to the `admin/viewer/creator` set, but it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can define role ids in an enum instead of a union, and then use a helper function to transform an array of role definitions into a typed map.

```
export type Role = {
  id: RoleId;
  name: string
}

export enum RoleId {
  Admin = 'admin',
  Viewer = 'viewer',
  Creator = 'creator'
}

const roles = [
  { id: RoleId.Admin, name: 'Administrator' },
  { id: RoleId.Viewer, name: 'Viewer' },
  { id: RoleId.Creator, name: 'Creator' }
];

function makeDictionary<T extends Record<string, any>>(arr: T[], keyname: keyof T): Record<T[keyof T], T> {
  return arr.reduce((dict, item) => {
    const key = item[keyname];
    dict[key] = item;
    return dict;
  }, {} as Record<string, T>);
}

export const ROLES = makeDictionary<Role>(roles, 'id');
```

Note some advantages of this approach:

- the helper function does not modify your role objects
- the helper function can be reused to make other lookups
- the enum doubles as 1) a single source of truth for the hardcoded id value and 2) a passable type e.g. `(id: RoleId) => {...}`

Comment: I agree that it is more structured this way, but I'm looking to make code more concise (as well as type safe). In your solution `Admin` / `admin` still occurs 3 times (still an improvement on my original code, since yours prevents typos).